# Generate multiple words from string reading an file

Tags: php

I have file which contain one very long line string with only letters. No spaces, no new lines.

Currently I'm trying to create function which take two parameters - how many chars and how many words and creates random words.

Example 3 chars, 4 words - `asd`, `jhH`, `OPa`, `BaK`.

This is my current function

```
function randomStringWords($words = 0, $chars = 0) {
    
    $fileRead = fopen("myFile.txt", "r");
    
    if ($fileRead) {
        while (($line = fgets($fileRead)) !== false) {
            $charactersLength = strlen($line);
            $randomString = '';
            
            if ($chars >= 3 && $chars <= 8) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $words; $i++) {
                    $randomString = $line[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
                }
            }
        }

        fclose($fileRead);
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$myRandomString = randomStringWords(3, 4);

echo $myRandomString;
```

`$myRandomString` should return 3 chars 4 words. Instead, returns one single random char.

Update: string example from file

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

If I pass `words = 3` and `chars = 4` the output should be random 3 words with 4 chars each:

```
asPd
Plwi
OGfw
```

If I pass `words = 3` and `chars = 3` the output should be random 3 words with 3 chars each:

```
yYd
asd
Ikl
```

and so on..

Comment: Can you give an example of the string in the file? And maybe one or two examples of that you expect as an output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly where you want to be. Just little things and it should work.

```
$randomString = '';

if ($chars >= 3 && $chars <= 8) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $words; $i++) { // first loop over how many words you need
        for ($j = 0; $j < $chars; $j++) { // then we loop over the needed chars
            $randomString .= $line[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)]; // .= to add to the existing string
        }
        $randomString .= ' '; // add a space after each word, you could also add each word to an array here
    }
}
```

Let's go over my code comments:

1. You only had one loop for words, not considering the number of wanted chars. Adding a second loop for the chars will fix this
2. `$randomString = ...` will redeclare the whole variable, that's why you only got one single char as output. `.=` will add a string to an existing string, just like `+=` will add a number to an existing number.
3. Each time after the inner loop (the chars) is complete you need to add a space to it to make it a word (or add it to an array of words).

Tip 
The PHP function `file_get_contents` could be more suitable in your case since the file content is only one line. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents